# Can the Bifrost reach the TVA?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki-2021

In Marvel's *Loki* (2021), the four-dimensional location of the Time Variance Authority is never officially established. However, the Bifrost is shown to be able to transport multiple characters across space (but not time) within the movies, even if it is summoned from somewhere outside of the nine realms - Heimdall is able to transport Bruce Banner to Earth from an undetermined position in space away from the now-destroyed Asgard in *Avengers: Infinity War* - from which one can assume the Bifrost can reach to and from locations outside of the Nine Realms. Does this mean that the Bifrost Bridge can reach to the TVA?

Comment: No, it's never been shown to be able to get to another universe, so it certainly couldn't reach a place outside of the universes.

Comment: But is the TVA actually outside of the universes?

Comment: Considering it maintines the sacred timeline, I would say yes it is outside of all universes. Which means it's also not in any realm or dimension. It's outside all time and space.

Comment: The TVA is outside of reality, as evidenced by the lack of power of the Infinity Stones in the TVA. The Bifrost can't reach other universes, therefore, it wouldn't be able to reach the TVA.

Comment: As the last episode of Loki as shown, there is multiple TVAs (the one Loki ends up in and the one from which he came from). The TVA is outside the spacetime of the universe/timeline but still linked to it. And since Bifrost cannot move outside time, it cannot reach the TVA.

Comment: @Roberto ah, such certainty you have about [timelines and universes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252230/is-there-a-difference-between-timelines-and-universes-in-the-mcu)!

Comment: Good to know I guess. Thanks for the comments, if there's an answer I can accept that.

Answer (score 1):

The Bifrost Bridge has never been shown to move through time or to other universes or dimensions. The TVA sits outside of time and universes.

Comment: “The TVA sits outside of time” — sure! — “and universes” — [to be determined](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252230/is-there-a-difference-between-timelines-and-universes-in-the-mcu).

Comment: If it's in charge of going into each universe to prune the timeline, I think it's safe to say it sits just outside the universes unless it has it's own universe. Which sure hasn't been deteremined yet.

Comment: what hasn't been determined yet is whether universe and timelines are the same thing. The Watcher can observe different universes. Do the TVA have the same power, or can they just observe (and destroy) timelines within their own universe? If timelines (like we see in *Loki*) and universes (like we see in *What If...?*) are the same thing, how come the apparent meddling with multiple timelines in *What If... Doctor Strange Lost His Heart Instead of His Hands?* didn't destroy the whole multiverse?

Comment: In that episode it said it destroyed his universe. And I believe universes consist of time and space. The timeline is the flow of time. Meaning all events in all universes are basically the same when the sacred timeline exists, when they broke all the universes started to branch off.

Comment: yup. And according to The Ancient One, that universe had multiple timelines in it. So, presumably, universes and timelines are not the same thing.

Comment: Spawning timelines creates a separate universe. And either the timeline still happened the same way in all those specific splits or they are out there and different at this point.

Comment: So there's still at least one universe/timeline left over from that episode? The one where Strange Classic decided not to try to resurrect Christine? And that universe/timeline is fine now that Strange Classic, somehow travelled Strange Supreme's universe and got eaten? It's not falling apart any more? Why?

Comment: They could have all been destroyed

Comment: they could have been, but then why weren't any other timelines affected?

Comment: You're asking to explain stuff that's never shown. And then not accepting the most simplistic speculative answer. As I said in the previous comments. Those timelines created in Dr. Strange's world created a different universe at that point. We don't know what happens on any of those timelines anymore because they're focusing on the first one only that is continuing. Until it ends completely. According to the Ancient One he couldn't change it. So presumably they all ended in the same fate.

Comment: could be. I'm not sure any explanation is particularly simple, with multi-timeline and multi-universe stuff. I don't think your assertion — "Those timelines created in Dr. Strange's world created a different universe at that point" — is supported by anything we see in the MCU though.

Comment: A universe consists of time and space. You're assuming timelines run in the same universe, but they've already explained that's not what's happening. Without time the space is nothing, a frozen cell. With time then the space expands and builds and is. If a timeline is created, it's another universe being created. That's why in End Game they couldn't just go back and change the past to change their future. All they could do was get the stones and then change the future of their timeline/universe.

Comment: Could be, but that's not obviously what _What If...?_ is telling us. There's no indication that each universe we see in  _What If...?_ was created by time travel — no-one travelled back in time and told Agent Carter to stay in the room, or Yondu to delegate the earth pick-up to Kraglin and Tazerface. Apparently, new universes can be created without time-travel. That doesn't mean that time-travel doesn't create new universes, but apparently it's not the whole story.

Comment: I never said that time travel is solely responsible for creating new universe, but when it happens it does. The multiverse existed before Kang merged them into one thread that follows the same story, then they were split again.

Comment: So Kang destroyed every alternate universe? But now we get to see some of them again in _What If...?_, because Kang eventually got stabbed?

Comment: Destroyed? Never said that. I said merged. He started pruning timelines when they would defer. And it seems you're under the impression there is a set amount of universes and no more can be created. It's WELL established in End Game and now Loki that any event in our reality that was straying from the 'sacred timeline' was in itself a new universe, different from our own. Thus after Kang was stabbed events started happening and the TVA wasn't there to prune them. Potential creating infinite universes that can branch themselves.

Comment: “it seems you're under the impression there is a set amount of universes and no more can be created” — I’m struggling to see where I implied that. But okay, I think I see what you’re saying. So everything we’re seeing in _What If…?_ is part of the sacred timeline?

Comment: It's never really stated what these universes are. They could be part of the mcu and what happened with Kang and Loki, but they could be literal what ifs. It could be both. Could be what these universes would have become had the sacred timeline never existed in the first place.

Comment: "It's never really stated what these universes are" — sure it is! They're part of the prism of endless possibility! I don't think there's any implication that these are hypotheticals. The Watcher talks to Strange Supreme at one point, saying that saving that universe would threaten all the others — the intention really seems to be that what we're seeing is part of the multiverse, and that there are stakes.