# Where is the Time Variance Authority located across time and space, and could it be located in the Quantum Realm?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, loki-2021, time-variance-authority

In the show *Loki* (2021), the Time Variance Authority (TVA) is shown to be a massive city-like structure. However, there is no view of the outside world given from inside the TVA. Is there a canon answer as to where the TVA is located, in both time and space?

If not, is it feasible/possible that the TVA could be located in the Quantum Realm? We are told that "time passes differently here in the TVA" (Major Mobius M. Mobius, *Loki* S1E01 "Glorius Purpose"). In addition, it is revealed that time works differently in the Quantum Realm (making time travel possible for the Avengers in Endgame). Could this mean that the TVA is an infinitesimally small object in the Quantum Realm that can therefore avoid the proper flow of time? This is further evidenced by the fact that a version of Kang the Conqueror is the main antagonist of *Ant-Man and the Wasp: Quantumania*.

Comment: In *Doctor Strange 2*, we're introduced to [the Gap Junction](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Gap_Junction), a space between universes where the Book of Ashanti is located. How this relates to  [Citadel at the End of Time](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Citadel_at_the_End_of_Time), the [Nexus of All Realities](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Nexus_of_All_Realities), or where/whenever the heck the TVA is, is not yet clear.

Comment: I don't agree with the close-reason. Voting to open - even though it might technically be "future-works", I'm sure it's not opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In the MCU we don't know.** In the comics it's actually in the [Null-Time Zone](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Null-Time_Zone).

We can only speculate at the time. There is things to consider though. For example the two time travel technologies (the one the TVA uses and the one they used in Endgame) seems pretty far from each other. One you can see people shriking to 'nothingness' and the other just creates a door to where/when you want to go. We could argue that Kang is from the year 3000 something and is way more advanced than the Avengers but I would find it weird.

It could also be a place outside of time itself, like where is Kang at the end of Loki where we can see the timeline in the window. Mobius said that times passes differently but that doesn't mean that time passes at all, nobody seem to have aged at all (as seen with Renslayer who looks exactly the same between the time she is a minuteman and the time she became judge).

We will likely learn more about all that in the upcoming movies and Loki season 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does make sense but I still like my Quantum Realm theory.

Comment: @PeterNielsen I like it too! But it might be contradicted by *What If…?* episode 5, where we see a universe that has its own Quantum Realm where Janet Van Dyne contracted a quantum zombie virus. If the universes we see in *What If…?* are the same as the variant timelines we glimpse in Loki ([I don’t think they are](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/253295/440), but what the hell do I know?), then each one presumably has its own Quantum Realm, and presumably the TVA isn’t just in one of those.

Comment: I do agree with @PaulD.Waite, for me each timeline has it's own TVA but the timelines are composed of multiple universes with their own Quantum/Dark part. The thing I find weird is that in the comics there is only one TVA IRC. But it seems that there is multiple TVA at the end of Loki, (out of the MCU) otherwise why show us Judge Renslayer going on a quest, and Hunter B-15 trying to expose the 'first' TVA by proving they are all variants ? This wouldn't make a lot of sense since it would be erased by the new version of the TVA. Creating plot lines to erase them 5 minutes later seems odd to me.

Comment: "each timeline has it's own TVA but the timelines are composed of multiple universes with their own Quantum/Dark part" — just to be pedantic, I don't think that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yes sorry my punctuation / phrasing wasn't correct. I meant that I agreed with you and added my opinion to yours.