# Why is Uatu the Watcher the only one concerned about the Multiverse?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, marvel-what-if-2021, watcher

In *What If...?*, in the finale, Uatu the Watcher is the only one concerned about the multi-universe when

> Ultron with the Infinity Stones plans to conquer the multiverse.

Why is Uatu the only one concerned about or who wants to save the multiverse? Why don't other cosmic beings interfere at this point?

Related questions that come to my mind and that can lead to an answer:

> Could it be that other cosmic beings thought Uatu will handle it? or Could it be that they don't know yet how big a threat Ultron is? Couldn't Uatu ask other cosmic beings for help? Could it be that he knew the Evil Doctor Strange is more powerful than many cosmic beings and wanted to devise a plan with him?

From the plot standpoint, it would get complicated to include many cosmic beings. However, there can be an in-universe answer also.

**Edit: Adding some key information I've missed.**

"I have seen everything that has ever happened. Ever will happen. Ever could happen."
*―The Watcher*

"Uatu and Strange went back to Strange's dimension, the Mirror Dimension, where Strange pointed out how Uatu knew how the battle would unfold before it started as well as Killmonger's betrayal. Uatu then thanked Strange for helping him and his sacrifice to keep watch over the pocket dimension."
https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Watcher

It looks like The Watcher has seen all outcomes in all timelines. However, when Ultron breaks into Nexus of All Realities to fight with him, he says:
"I don't understand. This should not be possible."

It looks like this is the only thing he didn't see but then based on what Strange said it is implied that he knew how the battle will unfold.

---

It is not part of MCU currently but there are supposed to be the Protectors of the Multiverse.

"The Multiverse was originally categorized and protected by Merlyn, who established the Captain Britain Corps."

"There are other beings and groups dealing with protecting the Multiverse, for example the Time Variance Authority, or the Exiles."
https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Multiverse

Comment: It looks like a question that could be answered in season 2.

Comment: @0.. - Could you specify the cosmic beings you have in mind here? The answer/s might vary depending on the beings in question.

Comment: @LogicDictates Any cosmic being like abstract entities, celestials etc. or even Living Tribunal. Why wouldn't any other cosmic being be concerned and interfere when the whole Multiverse is threatened?

Comment: @LogicDictates Yes, I've asked in the related questions. However there are other omniscient (all-seeing, all-knowing) beings and I believe they would be aware of a multiverse level threat. I'm not an expert though.

Comment: @0.. - Which beings specifically have been established to be omniscient within the MCU?

Comment: @LogicDictates Currently I can't tell/remember from MCU but I know from Marvel Universe. There can be comics influences also. I know people are closing now as the question can be answered in season 2. I thought there could be an answer I've missed in the show or other works.

Comment: @0.. - The problem with answering this question is that we know next to nothing about the MCU versions of the beings you're talking about. For example, did Ultron kill all the versions of these being native to his own universe in _What If...?_ episode 8? It was implied that he was alone in his universe at one point, but we don't know whether that means he killed literally every other being in his universe, including the abstracts, or just the non-abstracts.

Comment: @LogicDictates Thanks, I see now that it leads to other questions as well. It is a big question. Hoping to get more answers in Season 2.

Comment: So far, the Watcher is the only being we’ve seen in the MCU who can observe different universes — unless He Who Remains in Loki is doing the same thing, which [is currently unclear](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/253295/440).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite he's "currently" dead. Presumably none of "What If...?" could have happened if he was still in charge and pruning all deviations.

Comment: @OrangeDog: possibly, although "currently" and "still" are tricky concepts when time travel's in play. And who knows what his other variants are up to. Apparently the TVA "still" exists, albeit with different-looking statues and a Mobius who seems to not remember Loki.